# Python: Email Payload

Tags: python, email

Is it possible to convert string to bytes without encoding it?, I have a program that will read an email including its attachments and I need to save the value (which is decoded using Message.get_payload(decoded=True)) of the payload on the database and i need to convert it as string but when i converted the value from bytes to string then try to write an image using it I get an error

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

which i tried to convert it using this `value.encode()` it does not have an error but the image wasn't written successfully. Any suggestions? Will appreciate it so much. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
bytes("hello world in bytes","utf-8")
```

And replace utf-8 with whatever encoding you want. You could also try this:

```
str.encode("hello world in bytes")
```